# How to access members of 2 classs in each other

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have an application that I am making in C++ using `wxWidgets`. I put all the `GUI` code in one single file up until now but, recently I have been trying to break individual section of the app into their own class/files to clean up the code a little. I made some custom events to send information from one class to another, which works for most things. But now I have come across a problem that I can't think a solution for. I have these 2 classes, `cHivesPanel` inherited from `wxPanel` and `cListCtrl` inherited from `wxDataViewTreeCtrl` which both are a part of different classes, `cNotebook` inherited from `wxPanel` and `cLibrary` inherited from `wxPanel` respectively and these 2 classes finally gets instantiated in the `MainFrame` class which is inherited from `wxFrame`.

Now I want to access a member of `cHivesPanel` class in the `cListCtrl` class and also want to use a member of `cListCtrl` class in `cHivesPanel` class.

How do I solve this issue? Because both `cHivesPanel` and `cListCtrl` have constructor that take `wxWindow*` as a parameter, which is used to determine their parent window. And it's not possible to create objects of these classes in each other, as both have different parent windows.

**HivesPanel.hpp**

```cpp
class cHivesPanel : public wxPanel
{
    public:
        cHivesPanel(wxWindow* window);
        ~cHivesPanel();

    public:
        wxDataViewTreeCtrl* GetHivesObject() { return m_pHives; }
        wxDataViewItem GetFavoritesHive() { return m_FavoritesHive; }

    private:
        wxDataViewItem m_FavoritesHive;
        wxDataViewTreeCtrl* m_pHives = nullptr;
}
```

**cListCtrl.hpp**

```cpp
class cListCtrl : public wxDataViewListCtrl
{
    public:
        cListCtrl(wxWindow* window);
        ~cListCtrl();

    public:
        wxDataViewListCtrl* GetListCtrlObject() { return this; }
}
```

**MainFrame.cpp**

```cpp
MainFrame::MainFrame()
    : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "SampleHive", wxDefaultPosition)
{
    // some code...

    m_Notebook = new cNotebook(m_BottomSplitter);
    m_Library = new cLibrary(m_BottomSplitter);

    m_Library->SetHivesObject(*m_Notebook->GetHivesPanel()->GetHivesObject());
    m_Library->SetFavoritesHive(m_Notebook->GetHivesPanel()->GetFavoritesHive());
    m_Library->SetTrashObject(*m_Notebook->GetTrashPanel()->GetTrashObject());
    m_Library->SetTrashRoot(m_Notebook->GetTrashPanel()->GetTrashRoot());

    m_Notebook->SetListCtrlObject(*m_Library->GetListCtrlObject());
}
```

Using this the app compiles and runs fine, but as soon as I hit the button that triggers the function that needs say the `Hives` object from `cHivesPanel` class in `cListCtrl` class, the app crashes with `segmentation fault`.

I also tried something like this,
**Library.cpp**

```cpp
cLibrary::cLibrary(wxWindow* window, wxDataViewItem favHive, wxDataViewTreeCtrl& hives,
                   wxTreeItemId trashRoot, wxTreeCtrl& trash)
    : wxPanel(window, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL),
      m_FavoritesHive(favHive), m_pHives(hives), m_pTrash(trash), m_TrashRoot(trashRoot)
{
}
```

**Notebook.cpp**

```cpp
cNotebook::cNotebook(wxWindow* window, wxDataViewListCtrl& listCtrl)
    : wxPanel(window, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL),
      m_pListCtrl(listCtrl)
{
}
```

but then I can't do this in **MainFrame.cpp**

```cpp
    m_Library = new cLibrary(m_BottomSplitter,
                             m_Notebook->GetHivesPanel()->GetFavoritesHive(),
                             *m_Notebook->GetHivesPanel()->GetHivesObject(),
                             m_Notebook->GetTrashPanel()->GetTrashRoot(),
                             *m_Notebook->GetTrashPanel()->GetTrashObject());

    m_Notebook = new cNotebook(m_BottomSplitter, *m_Library->GetListCtrlObject());
```

If can you tell me or point me to some code or video that can help solve this, or help me design the code structure better please it would be a great help.

Comment: I believe really nobody has enough time to read the whole source to get your problem. You should create an much simplified example to show us your problem. And maybe, by shrinking your code you may find your problem yourself.

Comment: I totally agree with previous comment that your question is too verbose, so not easy to understand what you really want!! Besides, your understanding of wxWidgets seems to be wrong. If you instantiate (and must do on heap) a window in some other window, it will be a child of that window. Your best bet in this case seems to pass a pointer of the class you want to call to the constructor of the class where the call will happen. Of course, this also requires proper forward declarations. Better would be to re-design so the functions needed to be called wont be part of wxWidgets hierarchy.

Comment: According the `wx` documentation all controls derived `wxWindow` should be heap allocated, because the `wxFrame` is responsible to deleting all the child windows when it closes. I thought about passing a pointer to the class I want to use in the constructor but this won't work. because `cHives` is instantiated in `cNotebook` (`cHives` parent window) which has nothing to do with `cListCtrl` and same for `cListCtrl`. I basically want to access a heap allocated member object from `cHives` in `cListCtrl` and also a member from `cListCtrl` in `cHives`, without doing like `cHives hives(win)`.

Comment: if you are not planning to call each other in constructors then just return a pointer of each class, for example `cHives* const get() const{ return this;}`, then call this in cListCtrl.

Comment: If I write `cHives* const get() const { return this; }` my compiler (`g++`) complains about both `const` and makes me remove them. Also don't I still have to make an object of `cHives` in `cListCtrl` to call `get()` from `cHives`?

Comment: it was assumed that you would pass proper pointers to each class via constructors and also assumes that both objects are constructed . It also makes me think that you really need to think on your design...

Comment: @macroland I can agree that my design is bad. I'm not that experienced with programming in general. I have tried a couple of things since my last reply, it won't fit here in the comment box so I'm posting another answer.

Comment: I edited my original post to the solution I tried. Its after the line `EDIT: -----------`

Comment: you really have to delete all the unnecessary parts and condense this question. Besides instead of telling stories of this and that please stay to the point of what you are asking with only and only the relevant code.

Comment: @macroland I have edited the original post again, and deleted the unnecessary stuff as much as I can. Please let me know if there is still an issue.

Comment: `Now I want to access a member of cHivesPanel class in the cListCtrl class and also want to use a member of cListCtrl class in cHivesPanel class.` where are those? Sorry if I dont see them but you still present loads of irrelevant stories and classes. If you would like  members of two classes to access each other, I recommend you read about `forward declaration in C++`

Comment: @macroland So if I forward declare say `cHivesPanel` in `cListCtrl` as `class cHivesPanel;` How exactly do I use a public function or variable from `cHivesPanel` in `cListCtrl` without an object?

Comment: @macroland I have successfully fixed this issue. I basically created a new singleton `class` and have bunch of functions that are needed from the other 2 classes, and have a `init()` in the new singleton `class`. You can check out the repository if you want to see what I did.